# Using char Inputs inside C recursions

Tags: c

I tried to get a input for a `char` variable inside a while recursion in my program. There are 3 main inputs at the beginning of the `while` statement which are `char`,`char`,`float`. I used conversion characters as `%*c%c,%*c%c,%f` for each inputs but it look like it doesn't taking the input values properly. Then it works perfectly when i change the order of the inputs as `float`, `char`, `char`. Is there anything that I missing here?

I Also tried changing the conversion character of the first char input as `%c` but then it stops working after the first cycle of the loop. Is there any other way to have char input at the beginning of a recursion? I can clearly understand the problem is with the conversion character.

I have declared all the variable above. 
Simply i want get that LCH input first but then the program stop working.

```
while(CUN<=3)
    {

    TOTB1=0;
    TOTB2=0;
    //Inputs
    printf("Enter the Distance : ");
        scanf("%f",&DIS);
    printf("Are you a Loyalty Costomer(Y/N)? : ");
    scanf("%*c%c",&LCH);
    printf("Enter the Vehicle type: ");
        scanf("%*c%c",&CCH);


        //IF
        if(CCH=='A')
        {
            if(DIS>80)
            {
                TOTB1=(80*13000.00)+((DIS-80)*70.00);
            }
            else
            {
                TOTB1=DIS*13000.00;
            }
        }
        else if(CCH=='B')
        {
                     if(DIS>80)
                         {
                                 TOTB1=(80*15000.00)+((DIS-80)*100.00);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                                 TOTB1=DIS*15000.00;
                         }

        }
        else if(CCH=='C')
        {
            if(DIS>80)
            {
                         TOTB1=(80*7000.00)+((DIS-80)*80.00);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                 TOTB1=DIS*7000.00;
                        }


        }
        else if(CCH=='D')
        {
            if(DIS>80)
                        {
                                 TOTB1=(80*8000.00)+((DIS-80)*80.00);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                 TOTB1=DIS*8000.00;
                        }

        }
        printf("Bill Without Discount : %.2f\n",TOTB1);

        //Loyalty Discount
        if(LCH=='Y')
        {
            TOTB2=TOTB1-(TOTB1*0.1);
        }
        else if(LCH=='N')
        {
            TOTB2=TOTB1-(TOTB1*0.05);
        }

        //Calculate the Total Loop count Exit when CUN=3
        CUN=CUN+1;

        printf("Total Bill is %f\n",TOTB2);

        //Asking further
        printf("Do you want to continue for another vehicle : ");
        scanf("%*c%c",&AS);

        if(AS=='N')
        {
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Usually capital letters are reserved for the pre-processor. Use lower case letters for variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `LCH` and `CCH` are defined as `char`, change the format strings to consume the newline (`\n`) character.

From:

```
scanf("%*c%c",&LCH);
printf("Enter the Vehicle type: ");
    scanf("%*c%c",&CCH);
```

To:

```
scanf(" %c",&LCH);
printf("Enter the Vehicle type: ");
    scanf(" %c",&CCH);
    //     ^  space prior to format specifier is to consume newline 
    //     which is inserted when user hits return key.
```

Consider avoiding caps when defining your variables.  They are conventionally used for `#define` constants and other pre-processor constants, as well as some standard `struct` names, eg `FILE`.  `camelCase`, or `lowercase` are among the better options.